# Marketing Cloud AMPScript date output question

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have an email in marketing cloud that has a date of 28 Feb 2019 however this needs to be dynamic based on the following criteria.

When we get to 1 March 2019 the dates year needs to change to 28 Feb 2020

This needs to happen every year on the 1st March. It relates to when a application period closes.

We don't want edit the email each year so was hoping we can use AMPscript to do this however not sure how

Is it possible to do this using AMPScript

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like:

```
%%[ 

  set @today = NOW()

  set @expMonth = '02'
  set @expDay = '28'
  set @expYear = DatePart(@today, 'Y')

  set @expirationRaw = CONCAT(@expMonth, '/',@expDay, '/', @expYear)
  set @expiration = Format(@expirationRaw,"MM/dd/yyyy")

  if datepart(@today, 'M') >= 3  AND datepart(@today, 'D') >= 1 THEN

    SET @expiration = DateAdd(@expiration, 1, 'Y') 

  endif
]%%
```

This should make it display the current year by default, but if the date is equal to or beyond 03/01 then it will display next year.

You would just display this by calling the `@expiration` var. (e.g. `%%=v(@expiration)=%%`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Tried the code however get the following error: The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client.
 Function Call: Format(expirationRaw,"MM/dd/yyyy")
 Attribute or Field Name: expirationRaw

Comment: Oops sorry forgot `@` in it. Updating now

Comment: Hi again, error how now gone however doesnt output anything :(

Comment: little typo, should be %%=v(@expiration)=%% instead of %%=v(@expiration)%%.

Comment: Please make sure to mark it as accepted if this resolved your issue to allow for easy reference for others experiencing the same issue.